# creating a slide show with Opencv

Tags: python, opencv

How can I create a slide show of images in a folder with smooth transition between images

```
 using cv2.addWeighted ?
```

Comment: OpenCV is really not the right tool for this kind of stuff...

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main() {

    auto img1 = cv::imread("img1.jpg");
    auto img2 = cv::imread("img2.jpg");

    // Make sure the images are the same size
    img1 = img1(cv::Rect(0, 0, 700, 700));
    img2 = img2(cv::Rect(0, 0, 700, 700));

    cv::namedWindow("Slideshow");

    for (double alpha = 0; alpha < 1; alpha += 0.05) {
        cv::Mat out;
        cv::addWeighted(img1, alpha, img2, 1-alpha, 0, out, -1);
        imshow("Slideshow", out);
        cv::waitKey(100);
    }

    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Note that this is just an example on how to use `cv::addWeighted`. It is not supposed to be used in practice like this.

You can tune the speed of the transition by playing with the increment of `alpha` in the for loop and with the `cv::waitKey` parameter.